# Show 5 database entries based on date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got this SQL query right now;

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE 
`type` = 'press' AND (`published` = '1' AND `time_start` >= '".$time_today."')
ORDER BY `time_start` ASC, `id` DESC LIMIT 5
```

The idea is that 5 articles are always shown. `time_start` is the starting time, `time_end` is the end time (just PHP's `mktime`).

The articles are basically calendar entries, only entries starting tomorrow should be shown (working) and only the first upcoming five. Right now, there's less than five upcoming calendar points.

How do I basically make it do this query `if num_rows > 5, else fill up with older ones`? Should I be looking at a PHP fallback simply overwriting the data with a different query (showing the 5 'newest' articles) or is there a way to work this in the query itself?

Question isn't as much about how it could be done as looking for the proper way to do it, hope that's not against the rules

Comment: use this ORDER BY `time_start` DESC, `id` DESC LIMIT 0,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you want a window of 5 events from start time onwards.. with it showing previous events in the case where less are upcoming.

Two viable options here..

**If you are happy dealing with this in the application logic:**

Run:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM articles
   WHERE type = press 
     AND published = '1' 
     AND time_start >= :time_today
ORDER BY time_start ASC, id ASC /* 'I thought id should be ascending here */ 
   LIMIT 5
```

Calculate how many extra articles you still need and then run:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM articles
   WHERE type = press 
     AND published = '1' 
     AND time_start < :time_today
ORDER BY time_start DESC, id DESC 
   LIMIT :slack
```

Simply reverse the first result set and append the second to it and move on.

**If you want to do this all in the DB I'd probably do:**

```
   SELECT *
     FROM ((
      SELECT * 
        FROM articles
       WHERE type = press 
         AND published = '1' 
         AND time_start >= :time_today
    ORDER BY time_start ASC, id ASC 
       LIMIT 5
           )
   UNION ALL
           (
      SELECT * 
        FROM articles
       WHERE type = press 
         AND published = '1' 
         AND time_start < :time_today
    ORDER BY time_start DESC, id DESC 
       LIMIT 5
          )) window_extents
 ORDER BY time_start DESC, id DESC 
    LIMIT 5
```

This works by selecting all possible records for the window and then narrowing down the results. It should also make good use of your indexes.

**N.B.** It looks like you are concatting the date into the query rather than binding it in.. I'd get out of the habit of doing this, even in a secure environment unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simply order by the time_start and then do a limit of 5.
So definitely you will get 5 no of row and according to the time in the time greater than what you specify in the condition.

( Provided you have 5 entries for any time after the provided time )

Comment: The problem here is that it needs to show the first one from 'now' and the 4 that come after that. The idea is that there will be about 40-50 different items lined up that will show up in the overview but those aren't relevant for the highlighted ones on the frontpage...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date1,
    IF((unix_timestamp(date1) - unix_timestamp()) > 0, 1, 0) as a,
    IF((unix_timestamp(date1) - unix_timestamp()) > 0, (unix_timestamp(date1) - unix_timestamp()) / 10000000, unix_timestamp(date1) - unix_timestamp()) as b
FROM `test1` WHERE 1 order by a desc, b desc limit 0,5
```

You should go with the PHP alternative query but if you want you can use something like this. TS speaking, if the date is in the future we divide it by a big number to keep it near 0 so we can compare/prioritize them from TS in the past. It's ugly I known ;p but ugly is fun. You have to add you test and replace unix_timestamp() by $my_now_timestamp and add some performance condition in the test to avoid parsing all the table...

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the time_start condition from where clause (`AND`time_start`>= '".$time_today."'`) and you have to change little your order by portion something like the below query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `articles` 
WHERE   `type` = 'press' 
    AND `published` = '1' 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN `time_start` >= '".$time_today."' 
        THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  ASC,
    CASE WHEN `time_start` >= '".$time_today."' 
        THEN `time_start` END  ASC,
    CASE WHEN `time_start` < '".$time_today."' 
        THEN `time_start` END  DESC LIMIT 5
```

If there is no 5 entries after the given date, you have to get the previous record to get count number 5. So have to remove the date checking.

Or you can try this sub-query also,

```
SELECT *
FROM    (   
    SELECT *,(CASE WHEN `time_start` >= '".$time_today."' 
                THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) oflag
    FROM `articles` 
    WHERE   `type` = 'press' 
        AND `published` = '1' 
) T
ORDER BY 
        oflag  ASC,
        CASE WHEN oflag = 0  THEN `time_start` END  ASC,
        CASE WHEN oflag = 1  THEN `time_start` END  DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` 
WHERE `type` = 'press' AND `published` = '1' 
AND `time_start` <= DATEADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY `time_start` DESC LIMIT 5
```

You will get five results in a descending order of `time_start` field. This is the best solution since you always need to fetch from database the 5 newest articles that start 24 hours from `NOW()`. Even if there are no records found in database with tomorrow dates for `type=press` then 5 older ones in descending date order will be the result of the query, which is something that you want as well.